Char instead of Varchar for Django Field
I have some text columns that hold exactly 2 characters. When I use models.CharField with max_length=2, it still creates a Varchar. I checked https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/ and I can't find the field type or parameter to pass to get a Char(x) column instead of Varchar(x). TextField too is not right for this. From what I understand, Varchar uses 2 extra bytes to store length info, and its a waste here. So how to I get Django to create a fixed character-length column?
Edit:
Going through this (CharField with fixed length, how?), it seems that there is no way to force Django to create a Char, it will always create a Varchar and min-max length validators can be put on top.

Django will indeed always use VARCHAR, so unless you write your own custom backend, it will always have a VARCHAR(2). You can however add a MinLengthValidator [Django-doc], and add a CheckConstraint [Django-doc] to enforce this on the database:
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
from django.db.models.lookups import GreaterThanOrEqual
from django.db.models.functions import Length


class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=2, validators=[MinLengthValidator(2)])

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=GreaterThanOrEqual(Length('my_field'), 2),
                name='at_least_two_characters',
            )
        ]

I believe you meant MinLengthValidator instead of MinValueValidator, models.CheckConstraint instead of models.CheckConstraints, and functions.Length instead of lookups.Length. Trying it out now.

@fishfin: aaarrrgggh, yes. Thanks!

I tried both lookups.Exact and lookups.GreaterThanOrEqual, they generated Postgresql ALTER TABLE "common_country" ADD CONSTRAINT "my_field_constraint" CHECK (LENGTH("my_field") = 2); and same with >= 2 resp. Thank you for introducing me to DB constraints in Django. So this also means that all DB constraints implemented in Django should be implemented in DBs Django supports.
BTW, its models.CheckConstraint.

"unless you write your own custom backend" not really, you can create a custom model field as well. (One of the examples in the documentation, specifically the BetterCharField, might infact be suitable for OP)

@AbdulAzizBarkat: I think the tricky part is to translate it to a CHAR(2) field, since the backends usually only map to VarChar(...): https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py#L113

@willeM_VanOnsem check this part in the documentation that's what the db_type and rel_db_type methods are for. Along with checking the value of connection.vendor it should be possible to figure out the appropriate type to use for the respective databases.
